# can submersible pumps be used for leachate from landfill that may have some solid particles of size 15-20mm?

Tags: pumps, environmental-engineering

I would like to know if submersible pumps can be used to extract leachate from leachate wells. The leachate is likely to contain solids of size 15-20mm. Further the pump should have diameter less than 200mm. The head required is 65-70m and a min flow of 500 L/hour. If not then please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some research - we are not a free searching service.

Comment: What was your resarch so far? How much suction head is available? How much actual head do you need in the well, 70m or does this include head for further conveynce o the water? (My thinking is that you maybe need to lift water into a sump using an alternative pump type, from there on with a subermersible)